# Maintaining constant speed of a CVT engine during a slope

Tags: automotive-engineering, measurements, matlab, distance-measurement

I am not sure if this question is related to this community. But nevertheless. I work on CVT engines, I had a new idea of modifying my controller during a slope or a gradient on the road so that the Vehicle speed does not take a hit.  I have a radar attached on the vehicle, which gives me information about an upcoming slope. I.e., at what distance is the slope (meters) and percentage of the slope (100% being a 90deg wall).

Before I continue, I need to mention that this entire discussion is in the Cruise Control mode. That is, the controller maintains the vehicle speed irrespective of the engine RPM.

The first approach I did was slowly increasing the engine RPM when the slope approaches so the vehicle speed does not take a hit. Below is the simulation I have done.

[image]

1) The red 1 is where I simulate 5% slope and the speed drops by around 10%.

2) The red 2 is where I simulate 5% slope again but before the slope, I slowly increase the Engine RPM so the vehicle speed drops only by 4%.

From this, I do conclude that increasing the Engine rpm is a good method. But I do it without any proper math behind it (how fast or how slowly I should do it). I want to implement it with a proper logic and math included. If anyone can help me with the proper math or guide me in a proper direction, I'd be grateful

Comment: looks like you should prevent the overshoot of the engine speed.

Comment: @SolarMike I have the total control over the engine speed. But how fast or slow I should be increasing the engine RPM is my question.

Comment: Not according to the pink line you don’t - it shows overshoot...

Comment: @SolarMike Oh yeah, I did not use the full control during this simulation. But I can do it. This was just a basic simulation. I want to know on what basis I should increase the Engine RPM while approaching then slope. Do you have any suggestions on which parameters I should consider and how they are gonna affect?

Comment: I gave you a hint on your other post: slope angle ie rate of climb and distance, you should know the total mass you are moving and the engine power... once you have absorbed all the power then the speed will fall...